# Can't uninstall Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation, windows-8.1, uninstallation

I have Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web on my laptop but I want to install the full version of Visual Studio Express 2013 (for both Web and Windows Desktop).

[Link to Visual Studio Express (full)](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-windows-8)

When I run the uninstaller from my Control Panel, nothing happens. It stays on [**this**](http://s12.postimg.org/vpyn4y7zh/screen.png) for hours. I've tried to run the setup.exe (downloaded from Microsoft) again and choose the "Uninstall" function but I couldn't because the same thing happened. I have also tried to run the setup for the full version of Visual Studio but without success. What should I do?

Comment: Since you've solved your problem, why not post what you did in an answer so others can benefit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with my Windows 8.1 and I reinstalled it. Now Visual Studio works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Do you uninstall with admin rights?
Is there a popup window in the background asking for user and password?

Comment: Nope, there isn't a popup window :(

Comment: I also tried to run the vns_full.exe as administrator from _C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{some_code}_ but nothing happened again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this and a co-worker recommended that I simply try a second time.  It sounded pointless without any changes, but it actually worked the second time.  I cannot explain why.  Just try it twice.